# Let $f:R\to R$ be a $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $|f(x)|\leq |x|^{1+a}$ then 
$|f'(x)|\leq c|x|^a$.

I tried to use the mean value theorem and I am pretty sure it is a good way not to prove that.

Comment: who asked you to prove this?  It is false.  You know too little about the behavior of $f$ to conclude anything about its derivative for nonzero $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:
$f(x)=x^{1+a}\sin(x^{-a})$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $a>0$.

Differentiability can be shown at $x=0$ using the difference quotient. However, the derivative does not tend to zero as $x\to0$.

Comment: Are you sure this is a proper counterexample? Could you provide a proof that it is continuously differentiable for all $a \ge 0$?

Comment: It is only continuous differentiable for a>0

Comment: however, you are right my counterexample is not completely correct. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The other counterexample was right.